# To find match between two strings based on word sequence in R Language

Tags: r, string, match

Please guide me if any functions in R Language available to match two words in sequence to another string (instead of matching single word to single word).

[image: Sample match]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want as a result but using `lubridate::intersect` and `splitsplit` may helps,

```
df <- data.frame(
  string1 = c("Raj ate food", "Raj is working", "Raj ate food"),
  string2 = c("Raj ate nice food", "Car is driven by Raj", "Raj us not having food")
)

for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  print(lubridate::intersect(strsplit(df$string1, " ")[[i]] , strsplit(df$string2, " ")[[i]]))
}

[1] "Raj"  "ate"  "food"
[1] "Raj" "is" 
[1] "Raj"  "food"
```

Comment: Thanks, I need matching score between two strings and it should provide more score if two consecutive words are matching.

Comment: @SivaMani Then you may start with the code above. It will give common words row-wise.